# Objective C - Unwanted black background behind circle

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to draw a green circle using `drawRect` but I'm getting a black background in the rectangle area around the green circle.

I need bounding rectangle's fill to be transparent.

Here my `DrawCircle` class:

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *ballBezierPath = [UIBezierPath rect];
    [[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
    [ballBezierPath stroke];

    self.opaque = NO;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
}
```

My research indicated that adding the last two lines for setting `opaque` and `backgroundColor` would fix the issue, but it still doesn't work.

Here's where I'm adding the sub view in my `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method:

```
CGRect positionFrame = CGRectMake(160,160,200,200);
DrawCircle *drawBallView = [[DrawCircle alloc] initWithFrame:positionFrame];
[view1 addSubview:drawBallView];
```

Have I missed something or is there a different approach I can take?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your current approach:

- the properties are set too late, after you are actually drawing
- you are setting those properties on each draw now, they only need to be set once
- changing properties could trigger a redraw, and you'll end up redrawing over and over
- you are overwriting `drawRect:` without a call to super. To make the `backgroundColor` work to either fill the rectangle yourself with that color, or have the superclass do it.

Move your view configuration to the initializers, `drawRect` is not a good to do any of that. Implement `initWithFrame` and `initWithCoder` (to support Interface Builder.

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setupView {
    self.opaque = NO;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```